# MCP73833 and status to RaspberryPi

Tags: microcontroller, battery-charging, pullup

I want to use MCP73833 as a charger IC with the ability to route STAT1, STAT2, PG to RaspberryPi GPIO. 
Those are open-drain outputs and should be pull-up, according to datasheet. The datasheet also says that PG can't be pull-up to the MCP73833's output but only to the input due to IC's internal schematic.

My question: how should the pins be pulled-up correctly keeping in mind that GPIO has 3.3V level and MCP73833's input is around 5V?

RESOLUTION

Below is my final schematic. Thanks to [Maple](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/187920/maple). 
[image]

Comment: Data sheet link?

Comment: @hanni76 I deleted my answer since it had some mistakes. Sorry.

Comment: @Andyaka Here is the datasheet http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22005a.pdf

Comment: Looks good, should work. Thank you for updating with your final schematics, might help somebody else one day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add 4.7~10k pull-ups to 3.3V for STAT pins and use voltage divider on PG pin, with 1.2k resistor to 5V and 2k resistor to ground.

UPDATE

Your comment made me think of what is really going on inside that chip with PG pin. I still believe that voltage divider should work, but in case it will disrupt the functioning of the MCP somehow, you can leave the pull-up resistor only and add a buffer between output and RPi, something like [NL17SH17](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NL17SH17-D.PDF)

UPDATE 2

MOSFET or JFET can be used instead of buffer. Here are some examples, inverting and non-inverting.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. Could you explain, please, why PG pin can be only used with voltage divider? What is different with it ?

Comment: Unfortunately the internal schematics does not show details, so I would simply go with datasheet explanation and pull-up to 5V as they suggest (that's top part of voltage divider). It seems they are using it internally for other purposes too, the datasheet is talking about "pulsing  PG to determine if battery is present" whatever that might be. Don't worry about it, just follow datasheet recommendation.

Comment: Try resistors first. If doesn't work then sure, MOSFET can be used. I'll update an answer.

Comment: I think a buffer is a better solution as it is a single component not needing extra parts. For example, TI's SN74LV1T34 is a tiny SOT23-5 IC.

Comment: It's funny, that is exactly the reason I suggested buffer in the first place. I hate having more components on PCB than absolutely necessary.

Comment: Oh, and speaking of that, you don't need R18 on the buffer output :)

Comment: The buffer's output is pull-pull. If it is 0 then no amount of pull-up will give you 1. You might consider another voltage divider from 5V to I/O as a way to detect external supply and disregard PG in software if it is not connected.

Comment: Or, you might use MOSFET after all, because it will not be switched by high-Z.

Comment: When Vin is not present then PG and buffer's A input will be high-Z. I have no idea what should be on Y output this time, most likely high-Z too (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lv1t34.pdf). But I don't want high-Z on Rpi GPIO, I want 0 or 1. That's why I added R18.  Why do you think  this shouldn't work ? Because the buffer's output cannot be high-Z ?

Comment: see 8.2 in datasheet. This is not 3-state buffer. And even 3-state buffers require additional input pin to enter high-Z. You can use 3-state buffer if you tie its enable pin to 5V. But then you'd need that pull-up and probably pull-down on enable. Too cumbersome. Just use a MOSFET as you originally planned.